# Should "neither/either" be followed by "have" or "has"?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

In school, I was taught whenever coming across the pattern "either..or" or "neither..nor", we should always consider the noun/pronoun nearer to the verb when deciding which form to use.

For example:

> Neither my parents nor John _______ (agree) with that.

In this case, we should use "agrees" instead of "agree" since John is closer to the verb.

Then I have a question. What if when there is only "either" or "neither"?

For example:

> There are two particles: quarks and gluons. Neither ________ (detect) in the lab in isolated form yet.

In this case, should I use "has been detected" or "have been detected"?

Comment: I'm sure that in this case "**singular**" is appropriate. So, "*has been detected*".

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing stopping you from thinking of the pronoun *neither* as a shorter way of saying *neither one* where *neither* is functioning as a determiner. *Neither one* is obviously a phrase that's singular, therefore, according to [**the subject-verb agreement rule**](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/modulesvagr.htm), the verb that goes along with the subject must be in its singular form if the subject itself is singular. That's why *has been detected* would be the correct choice here:

> There are two particles: quarks and gluons. Neither (one) **has** been detected in the lab in isolated form yet.

Comment: Though note that in real life, and especially in speech, people will freely use either "neither has" or "neither have".

Comment: It's interesting because I hear both and both would seem natural to me. Because "neither" could be a determiner or a pronoun. Then I saw this https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2017/05/10/we-agree-but-she-agrees-the-importance-of-subject-verb-agreement/ which would agree with you unless neither/either is followed by "of" then it could be either.